# Estimated time to Delete multiple Contacts via Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, bulk-delete

Those that have used the Contact Deletion (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) process for bulk deletes...is there any metrics on time to complete

According to the documentation you can delete up to 1M Contacts at a time. Has anyone hit this limit and if so how long did that process take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted 3.3 million in 3 data extensions.  They got suppressed immediately and then the delete job was "cancelled" overnight.

I still have an open support ticket.  *Looks* like it's finished after over 2 weeks, but I'm still awaiting final confirmation.

Comment: Did you do it in 3 batches of 3M? We are looking to just clear out the All Contacts. I wonder if setting retention to 0 would help and maybe do them 1 at a time. "Cancelled" jobs suck :-) thanks.

Comment: No 2 batches of 1M and 1 batch of 300k.  I probably should have done them one at a time, but I submitted them all at once.  I also set the suppression days to zero.